# How many Ip addresses does a router need in the following scenario

Tags: networking, routes

```
                 eth0      eth0                  eth1       eth1
                n1============n2----------------n3=============n4
                     LAN1                             LAN2
```

Let *n1* and *n4* are nodes or computers.
Let n2 and n3 are routers, n2 and n3 are connected directly.

IPAddresses *n1* & *n2* are *172.16.1.1* & *172.16.1.2*

IPAddresses *n3* & *n4* are *172.16.2.2* & *172.16.2.1*

Suppose *n1* wants to send a packet to *n4*, so in routing table of *n2* it has entry

```
    subnet       port
 172.16.2.0/8     2
```

Now, for forwarding the packet via port 2 does the router *n2* need another ip address?

What is type of link between *n2* and *n3*? if it is P2P, for the link to be up do we need another ip address assigned to it?

Comment: Please write standard English, including capitals.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, for forwarding the packet via port 2 does the router n2 need another ip address?

No. (Corollary: The minimal number addresses needed in an n-node set, assuming you don't do lewd things like NAT, is n.)

> What is type of link between n2 and n3?

It is irrelevant to the question. (But if you need to know, look at your setup.)